# How to Install Xubuntu 13.04 inside windows 7

Tags: xubuntu

I downloaded iso image for xubuntu amd64 but there is no wubi.exe in the package, is there is any way to install xubuntu inside windows 7?

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WUBI is not available in 13.04.

In order to try out Ubuntu 13.04 using Wubi installer, you will have to install 12.10 using the installer and then upgrade Ubuntu to 13.04. (not recommended personally).

I would suggest that you install along side, it would be the next best thing to WUBI.

**Windows installer is not compatible with Windows 8 or UEFI firmware, and is not available for Ubuntu 13.04.**<sup>Ubuntu</sup>

**You can't** install 13.04 using WUBI since Canonical dropped WUBI from 13.04

Users, on the other hand, will need to look at a virtualization app like VirtualBox if they want a low-impact way to try out Ubuntu.

> Canonical is planning to remove Wubi from Ubuntu 13.04.
>
> Steve Langasek of Canonical notes that due to increasing bug reports,
>   Wubi is not in very good shape for having a release. The Wubi 13.04
>   installer fails to detect other ISOs, the 13.04 installer isn't
>   creating user accounts, and isn't even working with Microsoft Windows
>   8. Rather than fixing it, Canonical wants to junk the work.
>
> Langasek says, "the Foundations team does not expect Wubi to be in a
>   releasable state for 13.04...I am therefore proposing to drop Wubi
>   from the 13.04 release, starting immediately with the upcoming Beta.
>   This will save our testers from spending their time testing an image
>   that will not have developers working on fixing the bugs they find,
>   and spares our users from using an image for 13.04 that is not up to
>   Ubuntu's standards of quality."<sup>[Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM0MDY)</sup>

[image]

Comment: i don't know why ubuntu removed wubi installer, wubi works prefect, if your drive is basic not a dynamic!

Comment: actually i still didn't get answer of my question. Xubuntu Must have Wubi installer as all other works prefect with installer also latest version works prefect.

Comment: I've added info in my answer explaining that WUBI is not availavle in 13.04.

Comment: The idea of dropping wubi is really bad idea!